# HTML button list hover bug

Tags: html, css

So I'm designing this simple website and it seemed to work well until now. I had been using Safari to test it, but I can't get it to look right on any other browsers, namely Firefox 3.5-ish. The problem is in an  used for a button row. In other browsers the buttons are pushed to the right, as if there were padding or margins on the, but I specified a padding of 0. In Chrome, the buttons go to the correct spot after hovering over the original spot but reset to correct position again if the page is updated via opening the inspector. In Firefox and IE9 they shift to the right but don't move back at all. Is there a way to fix this? Here is the code that is relavent:
**HTML**

> ```
> <div id= "menu">
> <ul>
> <li>
>   <a href="javascript:openPage1()">
>       <span class="menu-button">Home</span>
>       </a>
>   </li>
>   <li>
>       <a href="javascript:openPage2()">
>       <span class="menu-button">Dave is Cool</span>
>       </a>
>   </li>
>   <li>
>       <a href="javascript:openPage3()">
>       <span class="menu-button">Submit</span> 
>       </a>
>   </li></ul></div>
> ```

**CSS**

> ```
> #menu ul {
> margin:0;
> padding:0;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu {
> height: 164px;
> text-align: center;
> position:absolute;
> bottom:-120px;
> width:650px;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu li {
> height:30px;
> width:120px;
>     display: inline-block;
>     text-align: center;
>     line-height:30px;
>     margin: 30px 5px;
>     position: relative;
>     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
>     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
>     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu li:hover {
>     margin: 30px 10px;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu li:active {
>     margin: 30px 10px;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu a:link {
> text-decoration:none;
> color:black;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu a {
> text-decoration:none;
> text-transform:uppercase;
> color:black;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu a:active {
> text-decoration:none;
> color:black;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> #menu a:hover {
> text-decoration:none;
> color:black;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? I've got this working, but I don't see anything wrong... all the browsers I'm testing in look fine (ie 8 doesn't render the easing, of course, but it looks the same across browsers (FF9,Chrome 16, IE8). Also, if you could include some screenshots with the issue highlighted

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten an opportunity to put the site online. However this is the issue I'm having: http://imgur.com/3t0rh

Answer (score 0):

I also tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and IE8 mode of IE9 and worked normally. Try to use `ease-in-out` instead of `ease` in your transition properties. I really don't know what's getting wrong.